# Form won't submit once error checking breaks it

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a project where I have some error checking.  However, the form wanted to submit each time so I had to break the submit.  Here is what I did.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "order-form" }))
{
...

<input type="submit" name="btnSaveOpv@(item.Id)" value="@T("Admin.Common.Save")" id="btnSaveOpv@(item.Id)" class="adminButton" style="display: none;" onclick="SaveBtn(@item.Id);" />

...

    var originalIssuedQty = 0;

    function SaveBtn(id) {
    var quantity = parseInt($("#pvQuantity" + id).val());
    var issuedQty = parseInt($("#pvIssuedQty" + id).val());
    var stockQty = parseInt($("#hfStockQty" + id).val());
    var availableStockQty = stockQty + parseInt(originalIssuedQty);

    //Issued Quantity cannot exceed Quantity (you can't issue more than requested)
    if (issuedQty > quantity) {
    alert("Issued Quantity cannot exceed Quantity.");
    $("#order-form").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    return false;
    }

    //Make sure Issued Quantity is within Available Stock Quantity
    if (issuedQty > availableStockQty) {
    alert("There is not enough Products in Stock to issue this amount.");
    $("#order-form").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    return false;
    }

    //Present confirmation
    var result = confirm('@T("Admin.Common.AreYouSure")');
    if (!result) {
    $("#order-form").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    return false;
    }
    else {
    $("#order-form").submit(function (e) { this.submit(); });
    //$("#order-form").submit(function (e) { return true; });
    }
    }    
    ...
}
```

Here is the problem.  Whenever I try to submit the first time without triggering any of my error checking, things work.  When I trigger the error checking, things work.  However, if I fix the error and try to submit again, the page merely refreshes.  Any ideas on this would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with chrome developers tools or firebug on firefox?

Comment: show us your form html

Comment: I so wish I could Fabio.  Unfortunately, due to group I work for, we're stuck with only IE8's crappy Developer Tools.  No bugs come out from what I've seen.

Comment: I edited my post.  The majority of the html is just a lot of code pertaining to an ordering system and wasn't really part of the problem.

Comment: When is this function called?

Comment: The function is called whenever a specific button is clicked.  I added it in with my last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things too complicated.

This is a basic template on how you do validation and how you stop the form from submitting when it's not valid:

```
$(function() {
  $("#order-form").submit(function (e) {
    var isValid = false;

    // Do your validation here and put the result in the variable isValid

    if ( !isValid ) {
      e.preventDefault(); // If the form is invalid stop the submit, otherwise proceed
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `$("#order-form").submit(function (e) { whatever });`, you add an *additional* handler function. It doesn't remove the handlers you've already added. This is probably why it breaks.

Repeatedly changing the `submit` event handler is a messy way to do it. Instead, you should have a single function which handles the submit event, and that function should do (or call) the error checking, and `preventDefault()` if necessary (like ZippyV is suggesting).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  After I read what you had I understood completely.  Thanks again.